# Integrating a density function over an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Currently studying for my Calculus 3 exam on Friday, and this is the one problem I can't seem to get.

You're given an ellipsoid in the form

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

and are asked to find the mass of the ellipsoid using a density function $f(x,y,z)$.

My current method is using two transformations:

The first transformation is from $(x,y,z)$ to $(u,v,w)$, where

$$u = \frac{x}{a}, \;v = \frac{y}{b}, \;w = \frac{z}{c}$$

for which the determinant of the Jacobian is $abc$. This effectively turns the ellipsoid into a sphere in $(u,v,w)$, and gives us

$$\iiint_V f(x,y,z)dxdydz = \iiint_{V^*} f(u,v,w) abc\, dudvdw$$

The second transformation is from $(u,v,w)$ to $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$, where

$$u = \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi, \; v = \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi, \; w = \rho\cos\phi$$

for which the determinant of the Jacobian is $\rho^2\sin\phi$. Integrating over the entire sphere gives

$$\iiint_{V^*} f(u,v,w) abc \, dudvdw = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 f(\rho,\theta,\phi)abc\rho^2\sin\phi \, d\rho d\theta d\phi$$

I initially thought this method was solid, and it works for constant density functions, but for some reason it's around an order of magnitude off with densities such as $3x^2$ as given in some of the homeworks. If someone could point out where I went wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: After you make the first transformation, shouldn't you have $f(au, bv, cw)$?

Comment: I highly suspect it's because you're overusing the same symbol $f$ in every step, hence you're confused by your own notation. The correct way to write it is $\int_Vf(x,y,z)\,dx\,xy\,dz=\int_{V^*}f(au,bv,cw)\,abc\,du\,dv\,dw$, where $V$ is the ellipsoid and $V^*$ is the unit ball. If you want, you can call $\tilde{f}(u,v,w)=f(au,bv,cw)$, but then note that $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ are **completely different** functions. (same remarks when you change to polar coordinates).

Comment: If this is not clear, then write out the full computation with the specific function $f(x,y,z)=3x^2$ (and if you still don't find the mistake, then post your calculation here). You should end up with a final answer of $a^3bc\frac{4\pi}{5}$ (assuming I didn't make any mistakes).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Wow. I know the function needs to be converted to the new coordinate system, but I tried to skip a few steps and go straight to polar and completely screwed it up. Thank you, lesson learned.